# UITableViewCell doesn't show content in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The code is:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = delegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Inspiration")
    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

    inspirations = fetchedResults!

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
    let content = inspirations[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = content.valueForKey("name") as? String

    return cell
}
```

`fetchedResults` has some values in it, it shouldn't have problem, something should be wrong with the implementation of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: is the second method actually getting called? have you set your viewController as dataSource and delegate? Are you returning the correct number in numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: How do I know it is called or not? dataSource and delegate are set, and numberOfRowsInSection returns the right number of rows.

Comment: add a `print(indexPath)` statement

Comment: I put print(3) in both numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath, both don't print anything in the console.

Comment: add a call to `reloadData` of the tableView after you assign `inspirations`.

Comment: I think you didn't set the delegate and dataSource.

Comment: OMG you are right! I created a tableView inside the default viewController, and forgot to connect it to delegate and detaSource after I put them after the class. Thank you very much, you method is very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have both the delegate and dataSource set for your UITableView.

Try adding this in your viewDidLoad func.

```
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
```